# Error when loader.load()

Tags: java, exception, loader

I´m struggling to figure out what is the problem, I receive the following error when trying to do

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/leftBar.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();
```

Error message:

```
 Exception in Application start method
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in       Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/onfocusproject/target/resources/main/leftBar.fxml:11

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:103)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:932)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
at tutorial.Application.initScreen(Application.java:74)
at tutorial.Application.start(Application.java:57)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: tutorial.controller.impl.ControllerImpl
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)
at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:927)
... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: tutorial.controller.impl.ControllerImpl.<init>()
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
... 20 more
```

The structure of the project is the following

[image]

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: What is in `leftBar.fxml` at line 11?

Comment: This is line 11, thanks! <GridPane id="primaryGrid" fx:id="gp1" alignment="CENTER" hgap="10.0" prefHeight="819.0" prefWidth="492.0" styleClass="linear-grad2" stylesheets="@samplestyle.css" vgap="10.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="tutorial.controller.impl.ControllerImpl">

Comment: I guess `tutorial.controller.impl.ControllerImpl` is missing a default constructor